# SFMC HTML surveys doesn´t retrieve correctly on professional Outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud, html, survey

I have made a survey on the classic module on Salesforce Marketing Cloud and when  sending the email it doesn´t retrieve the survey properly within the body on my corporate Outlook. However, I can see it correctly in other ISP´s like gmail.

I can also see the correct survey layout in the preview while creating the survey

It looks like professional Outlook is blocked from SFMC

Some clarification? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that only certain clients allow forms - and some that do allow forms either put warnings or completely disable them from functioning.

To get around this, it is common practice to instead link to a form/survey landing page rather than insert it inside the email.

A great resource for more information would be: [Campaign Monitor - Do Forms Work in HTML Emails?](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2007/11/how-forms-perform-in-html-emai/)

Below is a quick overview of forms in emails:

[image: Overview of HTML forms in email]

To sum everything up, here is a good quote from the page:

> Given the sporadic support for forms in emails, **we recommend linking
>   to a form on a website in an email rather than embedding it therein**.
>   This is the safest, most reliable solution to pairing an email message
>   with a form. More people will see it and be able to use it, and as a
>   result participation will increase.